# Is it possible to add a transition (like in CSS) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, tooltip

I have a Javascript code that shows a tooltip when hovering over an HTML element. Now I want to give this element a latency of about 6 milliseconds. In CSS it is very easy with the transition command. However, I did not find a transition style command in Javascript. Is there a solution or do I have to change to another programming language?

Javascript code:

```
var bghtooltipin = document.getElementById('bgh-tooltipin1');
var bghtooltipout = document.getElementById('bgh-tooltipout1');
bghtooltipin.addEventListener('mouseover', bghtooltipinmouseOver);
bghtooltipin.addEventListener('mouseout', bghtooltipoutmouseOut);

function bghtooltipinmouseOver() {
  bghtooltipout.innerHTML = 'Go to Login';
  bghtooltipout.style.color = "white";
  bghtooltipout.style.top = "0";
}

function bghtooltipoutmouseOut() {
  bghtooltipout.innerHTML = ' ';
  bghtooltipout.style.top = "-99999px"
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` could be used.

Comment: Does your code work? Or does it work except for the 6 ms latency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

`bghtooltipout.style.transition = "all 6s";`

Answer (score 1):

something like this it works is Vanila JS

```
bghtooltipout.style.transition = "all 2s";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to interpret "latency". I will show you how to perform both implementations.

1. Delay.
   6ms would pass, and then the transition would play. In JavaScript, this is done as the following:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  // Code here
}, delay_in_ms);
```

2. Duration.
   If you want your animation to last for 6ms, then you would do something as follows:

```js
const element = document.querySelector("#testthing");

element.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  this.style.opacity = "0";
  this.style.transition = "opacity 0.6s";
});

element.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
  this.style.opacity = "1";
  this.style.transition = "opacity 0.6s";
});
```

```css
#testthing {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="testthing"></div>
```

PLEASE NOTE: In this example, the transition actually lasts for 600 milliseconds, not 6. This is because 6ms is just too quick to see. It just appears as an instant change.